# Spring Batch FlatFileItemWriter - output customization

Tags: java, spring-batch

I would have the need to produce a CSV File with the following requirements:

- Every field is surrounded by double quotes
- Double quotes are escaped with backslash
- Backslash is escaped with backslash

Input:

- Field1
- Field2With\Backslash"DoubleQuotes"And|Pipe
- Field3

Expected output:

```
"Field1"|"Field2With\\Backslash\"DoubleQuotes\"And|Pipe"|"Field3"
```

Is it possible to obtain such an output?

Comment: Values have just been surounded by double quotes, haven't they? What about your 2 other requirements?

Comment: I haven't tried  to implement it yet: in the question I put the input fields, and the output I want to obtain (with all three requirements combined)

Comment: Is [this feature request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1139) what you are looking for? If yes, please upvote the issue or add a comment with your use case. We will consider it for a future release. Thank you upfront.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I have upvoted the feature request because that would solve the "field quoting" requirement of my use case.
However, I would still need to specify custom escaping rules for special characters.
For the time being, I could create a subclass of DelimitedLineAggregator containing the logic that I need. What do you think?

Comment: Thank you for upvoting the issue. Extending `DelimitedLineAggregator` would work indeed if you want to add custom behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public final class CustomDelimitedLineAggregator<T> extends ExtractorLineAggregator<T> {
private String delimiterChar = ",";
private String quoteChar = "\"";
private String escapeChar = "\\";

public CustomDelimitedLineAggregator() {
}

public CustomDelimitedLineAggregator(String delimiterChar) {
    this.delimiterChar = delimiterChar;
}

// getters and setters..

@Override
public String doAggregate(Object[] fieldList) {
    if (isEmpty(fieldList)) {
        return quote("");
    }

    if (fieldList.length == 1) {
        return quote(escape((valueOf(fieldList[0]))));
    }

    String aggregated = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldList.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            aggregated += delimiterChar;
        }
        String field = valueOf(fieldList[i]);
        aggregated+=(quote(escape(field)));
    }
    return aggregated;
}

public String doAggregate(List<String> fieldList) {
    if (isEmpty(fieldList)) {
        return doAggregate((Object[]) null);
    }
    return doAggregate(fieldList.toArray(new Object[0]));
}

private String escape(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return s.replace(escapeChar, escapeChar + escapeChar)
            .replace(quoteChar, escapeChar + quoteChar);
}

private String quote(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        return quoteChar + quoteChar;
    }
    return quoteChar + s + quoteChar;
}
```

}

Comment: It would be nice to add code examples, told like this, is not so obvious.

Comment: @KaderLAB I've added the example code

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just want to process your fields before writing it. You could do it with these 2 ways

Let's say this method processes your field

```java
public String escape(String str) {
    str = "\"" + str + "\"";
    str = str.replace("|", "\\|");
    str = str.replace("\\", "\\\\");
    return str;
}
```

**1 - Process it during processor** - preferred

```java
@Override
public A process(B b) throws Exception {
    A a = new A();
    //Process b to a...    

    a.setField1(escape(a.getField1)); //For each fields
    return a;
}
```

**2 - Process it before writing in custom Writer**

```java
public class EscapeFlatFileItemWriter<A> extends FlatFileItemWriter<A> {

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends A> items) throws Exception {
        for (A a : items) {
            a.setField1(escape(a.getField1)); //For each fields
        }
        super.write(items);
    }
}
```